# Find index of item in array entered by user

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a edittext and allows user to enter the items.

```
`EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

String s=editText.getText().toString();

String [] array= s.split("\");`
```

Suppose user entered `D\A\E\B`. Now I want to find the `index` of 'E', how do I do that?

Comment: array[2] have E so use it ;

Comment: @Nikhil Kumar perhaps you could rephrase this?  The index of the 3rd item is 2 since java uses zero based arrays.

Comment: I know the index of E is 2 just because I know what is there in the array . But my question is user entered the array , so how do I know what user entered . I wrote "Suppose " , so I have no idea what user could enter .Hope you got my point

Comment: no . made point clearly please ...

Comment: Suppose user entered APPLE/CAT/BALL/SHIP/MAN  So if I want to know index of SHIP , how to find that

Comment: you have to compare every string with your string to find out its index .

Comment: How to do that Sushil Kumar

Comment: @NikhilKumar  have look answer ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is:

```
EditText editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit);

String str = "E";  // string you search for

String s=editText.getText().toString();

String [] array= s.split("\");
int index = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].equals(str)) { // use equals, not ==
         index = i;
         break;
    }
}
```

So, if `index` is `-1`, there is no `str` in user input array. If it is bigger then `-1`, you get the index. (`break` is there so you don't need to continue trough `array` since you find the `index`).

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function like bellow and use it:

```
int index getIndex(String s,String[] arr)
{
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
    {
        if(arr[i].equals(s))
        {
             return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

also this is not tested but it will give you a good view.

Answer (score 0):

you can find any index like this

static String data = "z/d/f/g";
    static String s = "f";

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String array[] = data.split("/");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].equals(s)) {
            System.out.println("index is:"+i);
        }
    }

}
```